# Compojure - how can I get the servers own IP?

Tags: clojure, compojure

My elastic beanstalk app written in clojure using the compojure framework dispatches an HTML document with a java-script that does regular timed refreshes of an element within the document, for which it has to query back to the server.

Only I don't like the idea of putting any url anywhere in that code, it would be a bit of a hassle to change. I could make it a config parameter so I could set it in the elastic beanstalk configuration, but I figure there should be a way to get my public IP by code. Only, I can't seem to find anything about that.

Is there a way to get your own public IP from within the ring server?

Answer (score 0):

Elastic Beanstalk should set `X-Forwarded-Host` header in your request which should contain the host hostname you can use in your application.

Excerpt from an example request:

```
{:headers
  {"x-forwarded-host"
   "default-environment.adfadsbxczvdf.us-east-1.elasticbeanstalk.com"}}
```